# Error: member - "Graph::V" is not a type name

Tags: c++, class, oop

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class Graph
{
    int V;

public:
    Graph(int V)
    {
        this->V = V;
    }
    vector<list<int>> adj_list(V);

    void add_edge(int u, int v)
    {
        adj_list[u].push_back(v);
        adj_list[v].push_back(u);
    }
};
```

I am trying to make an adjacency list using the Graph class. However I am getting the following error:

> **member "Graph::V" is not a type name**.

I want `V` to be the size of the `vector` of `list`s that I've created.

Please help me figure out my mistake.

Comment: `vector<list<int>> adj_list(V);` that's not going to work. that initialization belongs in the ctor member-initialization list.

Comment: What line does the compiler complain about?

Comment: Anyway, search for the _most vexing parse_. You think `vector<list<int>> adj_list(V);` is an initialisation, but it's really a function declaration, hence complaining `V` isn't a type.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think it should work, if they were using braces to actually initialise, thus defeating the most vexing parse - and if `V` is always declared before `adj_list` such that it gets initialised before. Certainly it compiles for me. However, I don't know that I'd personally write it that way though. If only because it involves a narrowing conversion from `int` to `std::size_t` unless it's cast. It seems more usual to put it in the ctor body.

Comment: @underscore_d it's not going to work. the member V isn't even *set* in the OPs code until after all members are default-constructed (i.e. V is set in the ctor body; even if what you were claiming is accurate, by then it's too late). move them both to the member init list and the problem is solved entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't magically resize as you're attempting. the `adj_list` member should be in the initialization list and properly constructed:

```
class Graph{
    
    int V;
    std::vector<std::list<int>> adj_list;

public:
    Graph(int v)
        : V(v)
        , adj_list(v) // <<===== here
    {
    }
    
    void add_edge(int u, int v){
        adj_list[u].push_back(v);
        adj_list[v].push_back(u);
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "You can't magically resize as you're attempting." Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Kakarot_7 you seem to be of the impressions that setting `V` in the constructor body will automagically grow your vector; that's not how the language works.

Comment: @Kakarot_7 and the other problem is that according to the grammar `vector<list<int>> adj_list(V)` is not an initialisation, but a function declaration, hence complaining `V` isn't a type. So, even if your reasoning for that line were valid, that wouldn't be how to write it.

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
vector<list<int>> adj_list(V);
```

The argument is not correct, you could use the container's initializer list like so:

```
vector<list<int>> adj_list{V};
```

But still, `V` is uninitialized, its value is undefined at the point of construction, as [WhozCraig pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64442808/6865932) these both belong in the object initializer list.

Comment: Right. Both `V` and `adj_list` should go in the ctor initialisation list, not in the body or anywhere else.

Comment: *"you could use initializer list like so"* - did you try that? The argument to decl-init needs to be constexpr (last I checked). If changing to braces from parens even compiles I'll be surprised.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I did not, I'd expect it to work, I'll take a look.

Comment: @WhozCraig By my understanding, it is allowed - and occasionally very useful - but as you pointed out, vulnerable to UB if the member doesn't get initialised/assigned until later, which is the case in the original code.

Comment: @anastaciu careful, you may find yourself ending up with a vector of *one* list with a single element therein (i.e. `V` is the sole element of the sole list. Maybe check that too.

Comment: @WhozCraig, yes you're right, I failed to read the question properly, your comment is on point. And your answer too.